# Emit most-recent N events

Tags: angular, rxjs

In my Angular 6 application, I'd like to show the most-recent N events from a continuous stream of events emanating from a web-socket.

Today, the view presents the data from RxJS `Observable<Event[]>`:

```
<div *ngFor="let event of (wsEvents | async)">
...
```

The array contains the last-N events and is managed in a service layer. Not very nice.

I'd like to change this to a bounded RxJS queue if that's possible -- can you help?

Comment: Did you take a look at the `bufferCount` operator?

Comment: The `bufferCount` operator collects `n` events and emits, etc. which won't show the last `n` events at any time, @ingo.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should be able to use the `scan` operator to implement what you want:

```js
const { range } = rxjs;
const { scan } = rxjs.operators;

const N = 4;

range(0, 10).pipe(
  scan((acc, value) => [...acc.slice(1 - N), value], [])
).subscribe(
  value => console.log(JSON.stringify(value))
);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/rxjs@6/bundles/rxjs.umd.min.js"></script>
```

You could wrap the implementation in a function to create a user-land operator:

```ts
import { MonoTypeOperatorFunction, scan } from "rxjs";

export function bufferRecent<T>(count: number): MonoTypeOperatorFunction<T> {
    if (count < 2) {
        throw new Error("Expected count > 1");
    }
    return scan((acc: T[], value: T) => [...acc.slice(1 - count), value], []);
}
```

Which you'd use like this:

```ts
range(0, 10).pipe(
  bufferRecent(N)
).subscribe(
  value => console.log(JSON.stringify(value))
);
```